# Can a US company employ Iranian person outside US?

Tags: united-states, employment, sanctions, iran

I have seen [this link](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/32539/as-an-iranian-can-i-sign-an-independent-contractor-agreement-and-work-remotely) about Iranians working remotely for a US company. But it's (1) old and (2) about working remotely while living in Iran.

I want to know that can I, as an Iranian, get employed in the European office of an American company and get the European country's working Visa?

Comment: Depends on what the company does... If this is a humanitarian company that does charity work in impoverished countries this would probably be no problem. If it's a company that develops military hardware then you are going to run into ITAR issues...

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "get the country working visa" mean? Do you mean a visa to the US, or a visa from the European county where the US company has an office?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I mean the European country. Edited my question, thanks!

Comment: @AliBahjati It's been 2 years now! Any update? Can an Iranian living in Europe apply to an American headquarter even outside of the US?

Answer (score 2):

If you are ordinarily an Iranian resident (have not fled the country) then 31 CFR 560.419 still applies, even if you e.g. happen to be working in Europe. The US "virtual embassy" to Iran [says this](https://ir.usembassy.gov/visas/faqs/) about visas to the US. They mention that an immigrant visa is technically possible, if authorized by the appropriate consular staff (a waiver of the normal travel ban would have to be issued). This basically makes it a matter of consular discretion.

Comment: This does not answer either the question in the title, nor (since the OP's edit) the question in the main question text.

Comment: He knows the answer to the titular question, answered in the linked Q&A; what this question added was "then come to the US". Given those two answers, what part to you think is not answered? I don't know what "get the European country's working visa" means. In other words, the question isn't clear enough.

Comment: I don't see "then come to the US" in either in the title, the question, your answer or any of the comments. While noted in the link in the question, this isn't what the OP has asked about. This question text, as edited, is clear to me.

Comment: I think its not the answer because after contraction with the company the Iranian employee will migrate the European office and wont be Iranian resident anymore.