# Can Iranians get a visa to work in the US?

Tags: united-states, employment, visa, sanctions, iran

1. I have seen [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/56536/can-a-us-company-employ-iranian-person-outside-us?newreg=2e5b04d515b44705bac6927411f6085a) and [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/32539/as-an-iranian-can-i-sign-an-independent-contractor-agreement-and-work-remotely) discussing similar topics, but my question is a little bit different: Can Iranians get a visa (probably H1B) to work in a company (e.g., Google or Amazon) in the US? I think it is not possible for Iranian who live in Iran but what about Iranians who are currently living in a European country (having limited or permanent residence)?
2. I also know some Iranians who got US visas for their postdocs in the US. But I guess that's a different story because they would get a J1 Visa, right?

Comment: See [Biden’s Iran Travel Ban **Repeal** Reignites Debate About Whether US Can Effectively Vet Iranians](https://www.voanews.com/a/middle-east_voa-news-iran_bidens-iran-travel-ban-repeal-reignites-debate-about-whether-us-can/6202745.html), which says *[Biden repealed](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/presidential-actions/2021/01/20/proclamation-ending-discriminatory-bans-on-entry-to-the-united-states/) former President Donald Trump’s travel ban on Iran and 12 other nations within hours of taking office on January 20.*

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for sharing! But does it mean Iranians can get visas to work in the US? I can see some regulations such as https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-31/subtitle-B/chapter-V/part-560/subpart-D/section-560.419

Comment: I see what you mean - a distinction between travel and work.